# bootstrap navbar doesn't toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I try the mobile version of my jumbotron-based page, the navbar doesn't toggle. I want it to fold out like in [the example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/#) but it doesn't. Maybe I'm missing some code, can you help me make it work? This screenshot is how it is supposed to look when the navbar folds out in [the example.

[image]

This is [my page](http://qlbusiness.com/ai), which is based on jumbotron but the navbar foldout doesn't work when I press the button to the upper right, it doesn't toggle.

[image]

My code (identical to the example).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Customer Service</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/account/do_login" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: check your browser console and see is there any error?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya There is no error message unfortunately.

Comment: check after toggle click

Comment: Please post code snippets to pastebin or jsfiddle, we can't help if you don't show us what you need help with.

Comment: probably your bootstrap js path is wrong

Comment: You didn't include Bootstrap JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to check your bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js. may be that are not loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the part where you import bootstap and jquery ?

I believe the failure is there. Because for me the example is working. I had the same behaviour before bringing my imports into order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This should be placed in the `<head>` in this order to provide a proper functioning of Bootstrap.