# Chrome shows error in bootstrap.min.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

The navbar doesn't resize when using Google-Chrome's Toggle Device Toolbar. I found a similar question where the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097963/bootstrap-navbar-doesnt-toggle) was solved by making sure the .js files are getting loaded properly. But in my case this doesn't work.

However, the same works fine in Firefox.

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #0E293C;
  z-index: 99;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #19BBD5 !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #C6DAEC !important;
  background-color: #0E293C !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#updates">Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#how">How to use</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#googleMap">Find Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The website has been written by following [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp)

Comment: did you load jquery first before loading bootstra.min.js?

Comment: try loading jQuery script before bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: You can visit the website [link](http://rebhu.com) @samnu pel

Comment: Just noticed carousel-control also doesn't work properly in chrome. But works as expected in Firefox. I will try loading jquery first. @Dinesh

Comment: script tag for jquery.js is opened before any other elements of bootstrap load so jQuery is loaded before any other bootstrap content.

Comment: Please paste here the full html markup.

Comment: @DavidKhasikyan please see the webpage by visiting rebhu.com

Comment: @DavidKhasikyan You will notice the error exists only in Chrome, Edge. The webpage behaves as expected on Firefox, Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was that I had an `<iframe>` element which was not getting loaded properly. Thus the `Error404` box wasn't resizing.

In CSS I added `overflow-x:hidden` under body this made sure that navbar gets resized when I open my bootstrap website on screens of different sizes. And in my html contained the `<iframe>` element in container.